# Is there way to change the default print layout mode in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page. The default print layout changes from machine to machine, Browser to Browser.
I want to provide `landscape` as the default layout mode for the user, but the user should be able to choose `portrait` if he wishes to.

I tried using

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: landscape;
    }
}
```

But this forces the layout to landscape without the possibility to change it to something else.

Comment: How would you like the user to change the layout? That may be the first question...

Comment: When you try to print any web page you are provided with a window giving a preview of what will be printed and some settings. one of those settings is the layout.

Comment: I don't think `@page` rules let you set a "default", you can either lock the orientation or leave it to the user agent - probably defaulting to the most recent orientation used

Comment: Yes, I think I'll have to leave it up to the user